# How to hide audio volume pop over?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, audio, settings

How can I disable/hide this automatic volume level pop over that appears when changing the sound level. Is there switch or secret flag to not show this when I change the volume using the volume keys on the keyboard (Macbook)?

[image: Audio Level Setting]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/303128/disable-volume-control-overlay-on-mac-os-x)

Basically it is going to

> /System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources/BezelUI/HiDPI/.

You'll see there a lot of pdf-pictures, one of them `volume.pdf`. You'll want to overwrite that one (backup the old one!) with an empty `.pdf`. You can also overwrite the `mute.pdf`, but I dont think that is necessary in movies.

When you open this PDF in Preview, you will see a white square, by default, Preview will show transparency as 'white'. As the illustration is white, and the transparency is white, you will see a white square instead of the white volume logo. You can turn the white transparency off. Go to View, Show Image Background (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>)

Comment: In case you are curious about this, like me, and open a file here in Preview and see just a blank white file... Well it seems that Preview must show all PDFs with a white background, and as the content is white... So you need to open it in something other that Preview.

Comment: @SteveChambers You can set the preview background in the Preview Preferences (Command , ) under General; Window Background. And you can turn On and Off the transparency in the main menu bar, go to View, Show Document Background (Alt-Command-B)